# Proper way to divide table data using an array PHP

Tags: php

I have this table data:

```
Date          |  Room   |   Reading   |   Pax
2019-05-27    |  B-1    |   1000      |   1
2019-05-29    |  B-1    |   1010      |   1
2019-05-31    |  B-1    |   1020      |   1
2019-06-02    |  B-1    |   1030      |   2
2019-06-04    |  B-1    |   1040      |   2
2019-06-06    |  B-1    |   1050      |   2
2019-06-08    |  B-1    |   1060      |   2
2019-06-10    |  B-1    |   1070      |   1
2019-06-12    |  B-1    |   1080      |   1
```

What I wanted to do is to group them up like this:

```
$my_array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  //group them up by room first, then by pax, then by dates
  $my_array[$result->room][$result->pax][$result->date] = array('reading'=>$result->reading);
}
```

What out I expect is:

```
Array
(
  [B-1] => Array
  (
     [1] => Array
     (
        [2019-05-27] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1000
        )
        [2019-05-29] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1010
        )
        [2019-05-31] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1020
        )
     )
     [2] => Array
     (
        [2019-06-02] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1030
        )
        [2019-06-04] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1040
        )
        [2019-06-06] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1050
        )
        [2019-06-08] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1060
        )
     )
     [1] => Array
     (
        [2019-06-10] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1070
        )
        [2019-06-12] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1080
        )
        [2019-05-31] => Array
        (
          [reading] => 1020
        )
     )
  )
)
```

But all the data with same room and same pax are together, I wanted to seperate them by the output I expected, because I will be counting the number of readings base on the # of pax and the dates between, so from `2019-05-27` to `2019-05-31` is `1020 - 1000 = 20 / 1 = 20` and from `2019-06-02` to `2019-06-08` is `1060 - 1030 = 30 / 2 = 15` and from `2019-06-10` to `2019-06-12` is `1080 - 1070 = 10 / 1 = 10` and I will add everything. How will I be able to get them grouped properly

Comment: Your expected output is impossible as it includes an array that has two identical keys (`1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// init data
$results = array(
array("date"=>"2019-05-27","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1000,"pax"=>"1"),
array("date"=>"2019-05-29","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1010,"pax"=>"1"),
array("date"=>"2019-05-31","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1020,"pax"=>"1"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-02","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1030,"pax"=>"2"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-04","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1040,"pax"=>"2"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-06","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1050,"pax"=>"2"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-08","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1060,"pax"=>"2"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-10","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1070,"pax"=>"1"),
array("date"=>"2019-06-12","room"=>"B-1","reading"=>1080,"pax"=>"1"),
);

$my_array = array();
$pax_current = 0;
$no = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
  // increment N-array when pax change
  if ($pax_current != $result['pax']) {$no++; $pax_current=$result['pax'];}
  //group them up by room first, then by change pax, then by dates
  $my_array[$result['room']][$no][$result['date']] = array('reading'=>$result['reading'],'pax'=>$result['pax']);
}

//Output
print("<pre>");
print_r($my_array);
print("</pre>");

?>
```

Comment: Oh WOW! This is some kind of a trick I wanted to learn, thank you very much.